# Removing items from SimpleDB without knowing the ItemName?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I have a domain in Simple DB that looks like this:

```
(ItemName  | Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 |
foo        | X           | Y           |
bar        | X           | Z           |
```

I'd like to be able to delete everything from the domain that matches a single attribute. For instance, I'd like to remove all items that have the `Attribute 1 == X`. Looking [at the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SDB_API_DeleteAttributes.html), it appears that ItemName is required when deleting items. Am I misreading the docs, or do you have to explicitly know ahead of time what the ItemNames are (ex: perform a select, followed by a delete)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to know the itemName() of the item you want to delete.
So as you said you would need to perform a select followed by a delete.